# Error Forecasting seasonaldummy Predictors

Tags: r, machine-learning, forecasting

I'm trying to train an Arima model on a time-series along with xreg predictors for every hour of the week.  I'm then trying to forecast the model for the next 30 hours.  For the forecast I need 30 hours of predictors.  So I've tried using h=30 in seasonaldummy function in the two attempts below, but I get the same error message in both cases.  If anyone can point out the issue with my code, or suggest how to accomplish this I would be grateful.

Code:

```
library("forecast")
x=ts(tsData,freq=168)
xregT<-seasonaldummy(x)
xregV<-seasonaldummy(x,30)
```

Error in seasonaldummy(x, 30) : unused argument (30)

```
Arima.fit<-Arima(tsData, lambda = -0.1803477, xreg=xregT, order=c(17,1,0), seasonal = FALSE)
Acast<-forecast(Arima.fit, xreg=seasonaldummy(x,30), h=30)
```

Error in seasonaldummy(x, 30) : unused argument (30)

Update:

xregV<-seasonaldummyf(x,30)  ##does the trick

Data:

```
dput(tsData)
```

c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, NA, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 
7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 9, 6.5, 9, 3.5, 2, 15, 2.5, 17, 5, 5.5, 
7, 6, 3.5, 6, 9.5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 9.5, 3.5, 5, 4, 4, 9, 4.5, 
6, 10, NA, 9.5, 15, 9, 5.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 19, 7, 14, 17, 3.5, 
6, 15, 11, 10.5, 11, 13, 9.5, 9, 7, 4, 6, 15, 5, 18, 5, 6, 19, 
19, 6, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 9, 10, 5.5, 5, 7.5, 5, 4, 10, 7, 
5, 12, 6, NA, 4, 2, 5, 7.5, 11, 13, 7, 8, 7.5, 5.5, 7.5, 15, 
7, 4.5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 17.5, 11, 7, 6, 7, 4.5, 4, 4, 5, 10, 14, 
7, 7, 4, 7.5, 11, 6, 11, 7.5, 15, 23.5, 8, 12, 5, 9, 10, 4, 9, 
6, 8.5, 7.5, 6, 5, 8, 6, 5.5, 8, 11, 10.5, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11.5, 
11.5, 3, 4, 16, 3, 2, 2, 8, 4.5, 7, 4, 8, 11, 6.5, 7.5, 17, 6, 
6.5, 9, 12, 17, 10, 5, 5, 9, 3, 8.5, 11, 4.5, 7, 16, 11, 14, 
6.5, 15, 8.5, 7, 6.5, 11, 2, 2, 13.5, 4, 2, 16, 11.5, 3.5, 9, 
16.5, 2.5, 4.5, 8.5, 5, 6, 7.5, 9.5, NA, 9.5, 8, 2.5, 4, 12, 
13, 10, 4, 6, 16, 16, 13, 8, 12, 19, 19, 5.5, 8, 6.5, NA, NA, 
NA, 15, 12, NA, 6, 11, 8, 4, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7, 5, 4.5, 4, 5, 11.5, 
12, 10.5, 4.5, 3, 4, 7, 15.5, 9.5, NA, 9.5, 12, 13.5, 10, 10, 
13, 6, 8.5, 15, 16.5, 9.5, 14, 9, 9.5, 11, 15, 14, 5.5, 6, 14, 
16, 9.5, 23, NA, 19, 12, 5, 11, 16, 8, 11, 9, 13, 6, 7, 3, 5.5, 
7.5, 19, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 7, 8, 7, 10, 11, 13, NA, 12, 1.5, 7, 
7, 12, 8, 6, 9, 15, 9, 3, 5, 11, 11, 8, 6, 3, 7.5, 4, 7, 7.5, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.5, 2, 16.5, 7.5, 8, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6.5, 4.5, 
10, 6, 4.5, 6.5, 9, 2, 6, 3.5, NA, 5, 7, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 13, 19, 
8.5, 10, 8, 13, 10, 10, 6, 13.5, 12, 11, 5.5, 6, 3.5, 9, 8, NA, 
6, 5, 8.5, 3, 12, 10, 9.5, 7, 24, 7, 9, 11.5, 5, 7, 11, 6, 5.5, 
3, 4.5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4.5, 6, 10, 5, 4, 4, 9.5, 5, 7, 6, 3, 13, 
5.5, 5, 7.5, 3, 5, 6.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 4, 3, 5, NA, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
5, 5.5, 9, 6, 8.5, 9.5, 8, 9, 6, 12, 5, 7, 5, 3.5, 4, 7.5, 7, 
5, 4, 4, NA, 7, 5.5, 6, 8.5, 6.5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 15, 6, 4, 10, 7, 
13, 14, 9.5, 9, 18, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 11.5, 17.5, 7, 8, 10, 4, 7, 
5, 9, 6, 5, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 6, 5.5)

Comment: Please mention the package you are using in your question, `seasonaldummy` and `ts` are not base R functions.  It looks like `seasonaldummy` only takes one argument. See `?seasonaldummy`

Comment: I'm using the forecast package, and I figured out the issue.  xregV<-seasonaldummyf(x,30) works just fine.